# Creating a shared library without JNI exports for use from another native library

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to create a native library that can be dynamically loaded from native code. I don't want this library to export JNI functions. How would you code and compile that library?

I already looked at prebuilt libraries in the NDK, but didn't find a thorough usage example for them - only examples of the Android.mk files. Is that what I'm looking for? If so, is there any full sample code for prebuilt libraries that works?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the same way that you do for a library that does have jni functions.  No checking for consistency between java and jni code is done until runtime.

If you want to build it separately, it may be simplest to set up a directory structure as for an ndk project, and just not populate any of the subdirectories other than the jni one - though you aren't confined to doing it that way.

If you want a flat directory structure, you can do something like this:

```
cat > Makefile
ndkbuild:
    /your/ndk/directory/ndk-build V=1 \
    NDK_PROJECT_PATH=. \
    APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=./Android.mk 

^D
```

Then set up your Android.mk in that directory.

And then you can just type 'make'